# redux saga, yield with function that return promise does not work

Tags: redux-saga

I would like to use redux-saga in my project and get stuck with one point.
here is a saga worker function that should sign in the user with a firebase authentication service.

```
function* emailSignIn({payload}) {

    try {

        const user = yield auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)

        yield put(signInSuccess(user)) //this line does not executed
    } catch (e) {
        debugger
        yield put(signInFail(e))
    }
}
```

The problem is that code after this line does not execute
And there is no error in the console. I just can not understand what is going on.

```
 const user = yield auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
```

function  **auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()** is returned promise. And yield should wait like await when the promise to be resolved or rejected, but nothing has happened.

Please give me anyone any advice about such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) you need to use `call` function exported from `redux-saga/effects`.

The first parameter is the `function` the other are the `args` of the function.

```js
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* emailSignIn({payload}) {
    try {
        const user = yield call(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword, payload.email, payload.password)
        yield put(signInSuccess(user))
    } catch (e) {
        debugger
        yield put(signInFail(e))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use call function as you wrote, but in my case, I got working variant only with such invoke of call:  call([context, fnName], ...args)